# How to restrict Docker containers to run on specific CPU cores or group of CPU cores

Tags: docker

I have 4 CORE CPU. I wanted to restrict some 10 containers which I am running to 2 only cores and leave rest others free.

is it possible, how can I do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the cpuset constraints option when running the container.

Example from Docker reference docs:

```
$ docker run -ti --cpuset-cpus="1,3" ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

Meaning your container can run in CPUs 1 and 3 (0 and 2 will not be used).

There are other CPU parameters as well for the Docker run command.
Please see documentation for more details:

https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-cpu-and-memory